# Dialog box if there is no internet connection

Tags: jquery, android, ajax, dialog, internet-connection

If there is no internet connection ,the user click the button ,it will show some error message using dialog box.here i tried `navigator.online` in my android mobile webview.its not working.how to show the message using jquery, or ajax with json without using java.

Answer (score 1):

```
private boolean checkInternetConnection() {
    ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
            && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
            && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        Toast toast = Toast
                .makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "No Internet Connection Found !!! Please Connect To Internet First",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    finish();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: see.. i am asking only jquery.not android java code already i mentioned

Comment: @Raj,could you pls mention why you need it in jQuery?

Comment: i want to check the internet connection using my html webpage

Comment: jquery ,ajax or any javascript